# Generic WiFI USB adapter drivers

Tags: windows-xp, wifi-driver

I have a usb WiFI adapter that I lost the installation cd the only identification numbers that it has is

> wlan 11n mini usb adapter  fcc id: Wklwl 6203 s/n 27110262066

A google search doesn't come up with anything is there anything that I can do to get Windows XP to identify it.

Answer (score 2):

Doing an 'FCC ID Search' on Wklwl 6203 comes up with the following info:

Your device was made by CC&C Technologies, Inc.

You can download the users manual from here: https://fjallfoss.fcc.gov/eas/GetApplicationAttachment.html?id=1223698

The manufacturers Web site is here: http://www.ccandc.com.tw  but has no drivers on it! There are some contact details though so you could try emailing them...or via this wikidev page, the following are compatible adaptors using the same chipset:

http://www.wikidevi.com/wiki/CC%26C_WL-6203-V1

- Asus WLAN 802.11N USB DONGLE MSQ-WL6203 WKLWL6203
- Brite-view WL-6203   WKLWL6203
- CC&C WL-6203-V1  WKLWL6203
- CC&C WL-6203-V1A     WKLWL6203
- IOGear GWU625    QLEGWU625
- Zinwell ZIN-6203     WKLWL6203

You may have better luck getting working drivers from one of these manufacturers: eg: here's the drivers at IOGear

http://www.iogear.com/support/dm/driver/GWU625#display

Let us know if they work or not.

Comment: I was able to install the IOGear drivers & Win7 accepted them, but the device didn't see any networks. Windows 10 has drivers for it built-in, so it worked fine on my win10 device. This is the information Win10 reports about it:
Manufacturer: Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Description: Realtek RTL8191SU Wireless LAN 802.11n USB 2.0 Network Adapter
Driver version: 1086.51.328.2013
Physical address (MAC): XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX

Answer (score 0):

I have a device with the EXACT SAME device information.

In case this is helpful to anyone searching for these drivers, I gave up finding drivers that work for Win 7, and just use this device on my Win 10 machine, which recognizes it OOTB. This is the information Win10 reports on the device:

Manufacturer:   Realtek Semiconductor Corp.

Description:    Realtek RTL8191SU Wireless LAN 802.11n USB 2.0 Network Adapter

Driver version: 1086.51.328.2013

Physical address (MAC): ‎00-02-72-XX-XX-XX

If you can find appropriate drivers for your OS - they should work

Comment: Hm, guys... things are getting a *little* heated here. Its worth remembering realtek's chips are rebranded for a LOT of different companies, and from experience, their generic drivers are a lot better. As such, identifying the chip is an essential part of getting it to work, even if you're on a different OS . This feels like as good an answer as any short of being a product rec